# Remove a decimal from many fields

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Need to remove a dot from fields within a column (varchar2 datatype).  The decimal is not always there, but when it is, it is always in the fifth position, and there are always two zeros behind it.
(12E4.00) We need to retain the zeros.

It seems a reasonable use of REGEXP_REPLACE, but wonder if there is a purely sql way of getting it done as well.  Under 100,000 rows and 28,000 instances of fields with a decimal embedded.

Appreciate all help flowing.

Comment: You need to retain the 0's?  So '12E4.00' becomes '12E400'?  You understand that multiplies the number by a factor of 10 to the 100th power, right?  And there are only 10 to the 80th power atoms in the universe?  '12E400` is an almost impossibly large number.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Actually it is a non scientific id, not a number. Varchar is the datatype. not all are E.  could be 45K9.00

Comment: @user761758 If its not a number, then this is not a "decimal" either, just a "dot" character. So you just want to remove the dot character from the string while retaining all other characters, correct?

Comment: corect... make the dot go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a simple `REPLACE`

```
SQL> with x as (
  2    select '123E4.00' str from dual
  3    union all
  4    select '123K5.00' from dual
  5    union all
  6    select '123K123' from dual
  7  )
  8  select replace( str, '.' )
  9    from x;

REPLACE(
--------
123E400
123K500
123K123
```

You'd need to turn that into an `UPDATE` statement against your table

```
UPDATE some_table
   SET some_column = REPLACE( some_column, '.' )
 WHERE some_column != REPLACE( some_column, '.' )
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  Have not been able to get it to work in the table instead of dual.    The table column has several thousand various values with a decimal in them, in the fifth positon followed by two zeros.

Comment: WITH x AS ( select (col_1) , '123E4.00' str from t1) select replace( str, '.' ) from x where rownum <100; Did in fact get all the ones with the exact match...... Thank you!! How do we go from the exact match to all possibilities? Again, thank you much.!

Comment: @user761758 - Can you explain what "didn't work"?  Did you get an error?  Is there a specific value that did not get converted the way you wanted?  Since you have an actual table, you don't actually need the `WITH` clause I used.  Simply run the `SELECT` against whatever table and column you actually have.

Comment: select replace(COL_NAME, '.' )   from TABLE_NAME    OR select replace(STR, '.' )   from TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME ... Tried several variations, no results yet.

Comment: @user761758 - What does "no results" mean?  Your `SELECT` statement returns no rows?  Is there a `WHERE` clause you're not mentioning?  Or are you getting an error?  If you're getting an error, what error?

Comment: select replace("col1", '.' ) from tab1; Is selecting them correctly, but not replacing them in the table.. is that another step then?

Comment: @user761758 - If you want to change the data that is stored in the table, you'd need to use an `UPDATE`, not a `SELECT`.  `UPDATE some_table_name SET some_column_name = REPLACE( some_column_name, '.' )`

Comment: Thank you very much ! Greatly appreciate your help... Have  a great weekend !